# Check if HashMap was modified (values added or modified)

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a method that iterates over the HashMap to get the total integer number of all of the values. I would like to avoid iterating over the entire map and finding the sum if the HashMap wasn't changed since the last time this method was called on.

How do I check whether new values or old values were modified in a HashMap? Is there such a way?

Comment: Could use `hashCode` method, store the value and compare it to next call of `hashCode`.

Comment: Depending on the size of the `Map` calculating the `hashCode` may be quite expensive - so you might want to go with the other suggestion and set a flag when the `Map` is modified.

Comment: @Mo2: It's good that you didn't consider using the hashCode to recognize modifications, since modifications to the map not necessarily cause a change in the map's hashCode.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the sum of the values or count the number of values? It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jarnbjo Looks to me like a `Map<K, ? extends Number>` and the OP wants the sum of all the values.

Comment: @Boris: Perhaps. But that is not what he's asking for.

Comment: Yes, I am summing all of the values inside the Map. I want to avoid doing this if the Map was never changed and simply return the old value.

Comment: @Mo2: Then please modify your question and make it clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear. Edited.

Comment: @Mo2 The question still says you want the "total integer number" of all the values.  That sounds to me like a count, not a sum.  If you want a sum, you should change those words.

Comment: @BoristheSpider got it, seems I've completely misunderstood the question, will remove the comment thou, I thought OP was asking how to be sure to iterate on an unmodifiable snapshot of the initial map

Comment: @BigMike `Collections.unmodifiableXXX` **is not a snapshot**. It is a view, that is why it is _unmodifiable_ not **not** _immutable_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I add a new answer that will not be affected by clock work-around:

```
public class YourMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {

    private int state = 0;

    public YourMap() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        state++;
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    public boolean isUpdated(int state) {
        return (state < this.state);
    }

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }
    ... // Do the same with clear, remove... methods.
}
```

Then in your code:

```
public static void Main() {
    new YourMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new YourMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int state = myMap.getState();
    myMap.put(1, 2);
    System.out.println(myMap.isUpdated(state));  // will print true.
    if (!myMap.isUpdated()) {  // in this demo, it will never go in this if.
        // call your process...
    }
}
```

This one is efficient and you will not have problems you should have with `currentTimeMilliseconds`.

Comment: @assylias `modCount` is package-private and, so, not visible.

Comment: I thought it was protected - my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Extend HashMap; override the methods that change values, and set a flag indicating that some value has changed.  Provide a method to test this value, and probably one to reset it.  Think about concurrency if it's an issue in your application.

(I am trusting that you understand how to extend a class, and that overriding the methods does not mean that you have to reimplement all of them (super is your friend).  This whole class doesn't seem to me, at first glance, to be more than 30-40  lines of code.)

Comment: +1 for an OO approach. A wrapper would also work, and save you overriding collection classes.

Comment: The wrapper would provide the functionality specified; however, the user of a wrapper could not pass the wrapper as a parameter to a method that needed a HashMap.  If he extends HashMap, a user could do that.

Comment: +1 - really OP just needs to override `clear()`,`put()`, `putAll()`, and `remove()`, I think.

Comment: @BattleBarnes a few more methods in Java 8.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ahh, I haven't made the switch yet. I guess I'm off to look at documentation!

Comment: Oh, my apologies for the apparent plagiarism.  I honestly started typing my answer before yours appeared - I just typed it slowly.